# Adding a script tag to every product page in magento 2 using module

Tags: javascript, php, magento2

I'm new to magento.

I'm created a module-2 module from below mentioned tutorial.

```
http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/
```

With that module I'm injecting script into the page. But with this I'm limited to execute only on my module page i.e.,

```
http://localhost/magento2/helloworld
```

I have a sample store installed, but what should I do if I want my module to be executed on any product page.

Please help me understand. Pointing to an article would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your css and js file inside of  tag in the layout xml.
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Namespace_YourModule::script.js"/>
        <css src="Namespace_YourModule::style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the article that solves this specific problem.

https://mage2.pro/t/topic/34

In this he has added script files by default rather than by route.

**edit:** 
In another article he has given information on conditional loading of script and css files.

http://www.webspeaks.in/2016/03/how-to-add-css-and-js-in-magento-2-custom-module.html